# Create an accessing point into other classes using PHP magic __set and __get methods

Tags: php, magic-methods

I am making a framework with PHP. 
I was struggling to make a simple way I could use other objects in other classes. Making globals, or using `__construct`'s parameters was just not the viable option for me.

I coded exactly what I dreamed about. With the use of the awesome `__autoload` function, the present system works like this:

```
class Index extends Core
{
    public $house = "what a pretty house";
    public function tester()
    {
        $this->view->get(); 
        // Creating the property view with __get and accessing the class with the help of __autoloading. 

    }
}
```

While this works perfect, It does not work when creating a property...

```
$this->house = "Not so pretty";  // Still prints the original value
```

This is the Core function, through which it all works

```
class Core 
{
    function __get($property_name)
    {
        $include_directories = array("library", "view", "action", "errors", "template");
        if(!property_exists(__CLASS__, $property_name))
        {   
            foreach($include_directories as $include_directory)
            {
                $path = $this->appRoot() . $include_directory . "/" . $property_name . ".php";
                if(file_exists($path))
                {
                    return new $property_name;
                    break; // exit the loop when the porperty if found
                }

                else 
                {
                    echo "CORE__GET:PROPERTY_NOT_MADE;</BR>";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function __set($property_name, $property_value)
    {
    // What should I put here?
    }

    public function appRoot()
    {
        return $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/application/";
    }   
}
```

And this is the __autoload function...

```
function __autoload($class_name)
{
    $include_directories = array("library", "view", "action", "errors", "template");
    foreach($include_directories as $include_directory)
    {
        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/application/" . $include_directory . "/" . $class_name . ".php";
        if(file_exists($path))
        {
            include($path);
        }
    }
}
```

I love my new system, because it works exactly how I need it to work. However, I would love to explore new ways to do something similar.

I hope I can overcome this problem, it's holding me down in my work. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve: btw you are not using any `autoload` function, you are just creating a new instance of some class via a magic getter [which doesn't make much sense, but anyways]. I think you just want to hear about namespaces and dependency injection providers - have a look at [Composer autoloading](http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) as well.

Comment: @moonwave99 The autoload function is in index.php, I guess I forgot to include it. I just want a nice and clean way to use classes in other classes.

Comment: You are creating a new object each time that getter is called, store the `new $property_name` somewhere and reuse it for subsequent calls.

Comment: @Rasteril namespaces and dependency injection, good search! :))

Comment: @DCoder Thank you very much, for pointing that out. I think I am going to reformulate my question. I need it to finish my project.